# cannot import name '_errors' from partially initialized module 'h5py'

Tags: python, h5py

What is the reason for the following error even though I installed h5py?

File ~\Desktop\gan\venv\lib\site-packages\h5py_*init*_.py:25
from. import_errors

ImportError: cannot import name '*errors' from partially initialized module 'h5py' (most likely due to a circular import) (C:\Users\Qazal\Desktop\gan\venv\lib\site-packages\h5py_*init**.py)

When I run this:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from . import _errors
import h5py.h5py_errors
from keras.layers import LeakyReLU, UpSampling2D, Dropout
# Bringing in tensorflow

gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
for gpu in gpus: 
    tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpu, True)
    # Brining in tensorflow datasets for fashion mnist 
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
# Bringing in matplotlib for viz stuff
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# Use the tensorflow datasets api to bring in the data source
ds = tfds.load('fashion_mnist', split='train')

a=ds.as_numpy_iterator().next()['label']
# Do some data transformation
import numpy as np
# Setup connection aka iterator
dataiterator = ds.as_numpy_iterator()
# Getting data out of the pipeline
b=dataiterator.next()['image']
# Setup the subplot formatting 
fig, ax = plt.subplots(ncols=4, figsize=(20,20))
# Loop four times and get images 
for idx in range(4): 
    # Grab an image and label
    sample = dataiterator.next()
    # Plot the image using a specific subplot 
    ax[idx].imshow(np.squeeze(sample['image']))
    # Appending the image label as the plot title 
    ax[idx].title.set_text(sample['label'])
    # Scale and return images only 
def scale_images(data): 
    image = data['image']
    return image / 255
# Reload the dataset 
ds = tfds.load('fashion_mnist', split='train')
# Running the dataset through the scale_images preprocessing step
ds = ds.map(scale_images) 
# Cache the dataset for that batch 
ds = ds.cache()
# Shuffle it up 
ds = ds.shuffle(60000)

ds = ds.batch(128)
# Reduces the likelihood of bottlenecking 
ds = ds.prefetch(64)
c=ds.as_numpy_iterator().next().shape
# Bring in the sequential api for the generator and discriminator
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
# Bring in the layers for the neural network
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, Dense, Flatten, Reshape, LeakyReL
def build_generator(): 
    model = Sequential()
    
    # Takes in random values and reshapes it to 7x7x128
    # Beginnings of a generated image
    model.add(Dense(7*7*128, input_dim=128))
    model.add(LeakyReLU(0.2))
    model.add(Reshape((7,7,128)))
    
    # Upsampling block 1 
    model.add(UpSampling2D())
    model.add(Conv2D(128, 5, padding='same'))
    model.add(LeakyReLU(0.2))
    
    # Upsampling block 2 
    model.add(UpSampling2D())
    model.add(Conv2D(128, 5, padding='same'))
    model.add(LeakyReLU(0.2))
    
    # Convolutional block 1
    model.add(Conv2D(128, 4, padding='same'))
    model.add(LeakyReLU(0.2))
    
    # Convolutional block 2
    model.add(Conv2D(128, 4, padding='same'))
    model.add(LeakyReLU(0.2))
    
    # Conv layer to get to one channel
    model.add(Conv2D(1, 4, padding='same', activation='sigmoid'))
    
    return model
generator = build_generator()
generator.summary()
img = generator.predict(np.random.randn(4,128,1))
# Generate new fashion
img = generator.predict(np.random.randn(4,128,1))
# Setup the subplot formatting 
fig, ax = plt.subplots(ncols=4, figsize=(20,20))
# Loop four times and get images 
for idx, img in enumerate(img): 
    # Plot the image using a specific subplot 
    ax[idx].imshow(np.squeeze(img))
    # Appending the image label as the plot title 
    ax[idx].title.set_text(idx)
def build_discriminator(): 
    model = Sequential()
    
    # First Conv Block
    model.add(Conv2D(32, 5, input_shape = (28,28,1)))
    model.add(LeakyReLU(0.2))
    model.add(Dropout(0.4))
    
    # Second Conv Block
    model.add(Conv2D(64, 5))
    model.add(LeakyReLU(0.2))
    model.add(Dropout(0.4))
    
    # Third Conv Block
    model.add(Conv2D(128, 5))
    model.add(LeakyReLU(0.2))
    model.add(Dropout(0.4))
    
    # Fourth Conv Block
    model.add(Conv2D(256, 5))
    model.add(LeakyReLU(0.2))
    model.add(Dropout(0.4))
    
    # Flatten then pass to dense layer
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dropout(0.4))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
    
    return model 
discriminator = build_discriminator()
discriminator.summary()
img = img[0]
d=img.shape
discriminator.predict(img)
# Adam is going to be the optimizer for both
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
# Binary cross entropy is going to be the loss for both 
from tensorflow.keras.losses import BinaryCrossentropy
g_opt = Adam(learning_rate=0.0001) 
d_opt = Adam(learning_rate=0.00001) 
g_loss = BinaryCrossentropy()
d_loss = BinaryCrossentropy()
# Importing the base model class to subclass our training step 
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model

class FashionGAN(Model): 
    def __init__(self, generator, discriminator, *args, **kwargs):
        # Pass through args and kwargs to base class 
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        
        # Create attributes for gen and disc
        self.generator = generator 
        self.discriminator = discriminator 
        
    def compile(self, g_opt, d_opt, g_loss, d_loss, *args, **kwargs): 
        # Compile with base class
        super().compile(*args, **kwargs)
        
        # Create attributes for losses and optimizers
        self.g_opt = g_opt
        self.d_opt = d_opt
        self.g_loss = g_loss
        self.d_loss = d_loss 

    def train_step(self, batch):
        # Get the data 
        real_images = batch
        fake_images = self.generator(tf.random.normal((128, 128, 1)), training=False)
        
        # Train the discriminator
        with tf.GradientTape() as d_tape: 
            # Pass the real and fake images to the discriminator model
            yhat_real = self.discriminator(real_images, training=True) 
            yhat_fake = self.discriminator(fake_images, training=True)
            yhat_realfake = tf.concat([yhat_real, yhat_fake], 0)
            
            # Create labels for real and fakes images
            y_realfake = tf.concat([tf.zeros_like(yhat_real), tf.ones_like(yhat_fake)], 0)
            
            # Add some noise to the TRUE outputs
            noise_real = 0.15*tf.random.uniform(tf.shape(yhat_real))
            noise_fake = -0.15*tf.random.uniform(tf.shape(yhat_fake))
            y_realfake += tf.concat([noise_real, noise_fake], 0)
            
            # Calculate loss - BINARYCROSS 
            total_d_loss = self.d_loss(y_realfake, yhat_realfake)
            
        # Apply backpropagation - nn learn 
        dgrad = d_tape.gradient(total_d_loss, self.discriminator.trainable_variables) 
        self.d_opt.apply_gradients(zip(dgrad, self.discriminator.trainable_variables))
        
        # Train the generator 
        with tf.GradientTape() as g_tape: 
            # Generate some new images
            gen_images = self.generator(tf.random.normal((128,128,1)), training=True)
                                        
            # Create the predicted labels
            predicted_labels = self.discriminator(gen_images, training=False)
                                        
            # Calculate loss - trick to training to fake out the discriminator
            total_g_loss = self.g_loss(tf.zeros_like(predicted_labels), predicted_labels) 
            
        # Apply backprop
        ggrad = g_tape.gradient(total_g_loss, self.generator.trainable_variables)
        self.g_opt.apply_gradients(zip(ggrad, self.generator.trainable_variables))
        
        return {"d_loss":total_d_loss, "g_loss":total_g_loss}
# Create instance of subclassed model
fashgan = FashionGAN(generator, discriminator)
# Compile the model
fashgan.compile(g_opt, d_opt, g_loss, d_loss)
import os
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import array_to_img
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import Callback
class ModelMonitor(Callback):
    def __init__(self, num_img=3, latent_dim=128):
        self.num_img = num_img
        self.latent_dim = latent_dim

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        random_latent_vectors = tf.random.uniform((self.num_img, self.latent_dim,1))
        generated_images = self.model.generator(random_latent_vectors)
        generated_images *= 255
        generated_images.numpy()
        for i in range(self.num_img):
            img = array_to_img(generated_images[i])
            img.save(os.path.join('images', f'generated_img_{epoch}_{i}.png'))
            # Recommend 2000 epochs
hist = fashgan.fit(ds, epochs=20, callbacks=[ModelMonitor()])
plt.suptitle('Loss')
plt.plot(hist.history['d_loss'], label='d_loss')
plt.plot(hist.history['g_loss'], label='g_loss')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
generator.load_weights(os.path.join('archive', 'generatormodel.h5'))
imgs = generator.predict(tf.random.normal((16, 128, 1)))
fig, ax = plt.subplots(ncols=4, nrows=4, figsize=(10,10))
for r in range(4): 
    for c in range(4): 
        ax[r][c].imshow(imgs[(r+1)*(c+1)-1])

generator.save('generator.h5')
discriminator.save('discriminator.h5')
```

Comment: "When I run this:" - What is the name of the file where you have that code? That *is* your part of the code, right? Not the library?

Comment: The name of the file is gan.
Yes, it is part of the code, I added the complete code.